# python need faster response with getch

Tags: python, msvcrt, getch

I'm trying to create a setup to blink a led and be able to control the frequency.
Right now I'm just printing 10s as placeholders for testing.
Everything runs and does what should, but getch is throwing me off.

```
freq = 1
while freq > 0:
    time.sleep(.5/freq) #half dutycycle / Hz
    print("1")
    time.sleep(.5/freq) #half dutycycle / Hz
    print("0")

    def kbfunc():
        return ord(msvcrt.getch()) if msvcrt.kbhit() else 0
    #print(kbfunc())

    if kbfunc() == 27: #ESC
        break
    if kbfunc() == 49: #one
        freq = freq + 10
    if kbfunc() == 48: #zero
        freq = freq - 10
```

Now when it starts up, the freq change portion seems buggy like it's not reading all the time or I have to time the press just right. The break line has no problem whenever pressed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from msvcrt import getch,kbhit
import time

def read_kb():
    return ord(getch()) if kbhit() else 0
def next_state(state):
    return (state + 1)%2 # 1 -> 0, 0 -> 1

freq = 1.0 # in blinks per second
state = 0
while freq > 0:
    print(state)
    state = next_state(state)

    key = read_kb()

    if key == 27: #ESC
        break
    if key == 49: #one
        freq = freq + 1.0
    if key == 48: #zero
        freq = max(freq - 1.0, 1.0)

    time.sleep(0.5/freq)
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean there Karoly and thanks for the example j2ko

Answer (score 2):

There should be only one `kbfunc()` call. Store the result in a variable.

E.g.: In your code if the key isn't `Esc`, you'll read the keyboard again.